# use regular expression to select part of html tag from string in php

Tags: php, regex, dom, search

I would like to select the string in a div tag in php. I plan to do it with regular expression. But is there a better way?

Like this: `Hello there <div>how are you?</div>. Please <div>send my regards</div> to Allan.`

I would like to retrieve all texts in and together with div tag like:

```
"<div>how are you?</div>"
"<div>send my regards</div>"
```

May I know how to do?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

> I plan to do it with regular expression.

#### Nope , don't do that. The concrete reason [here](http://blog.codinghorror.com/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way/)

> But is there a better way?

#### Yes , use a `DOM Parser` for this ..

```
$html='Hello there <div>how are you?</div>. Please <div>send my regards</div> to Allan.';
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$divText='';
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('div') as $tag) {
      $divText.=$dom->saveHTML($tag);
}
echo $divText;
```

Comment: Better save the div as HTML (keeps escaping) $divText .= $tag->ownerDocument->saveHtml($tag);

Comment: Yes but DomDocument is really almost as bad as regex.

Comment: So what are your suggestions ?

Comment: I have this error when running the code above.   Warning: DOMDocument::saveHTML() expects exactly 0 parameters, 1 given in /home/.....

Comment: The $node argument for DOMDocument::saveHtml() was added in PHP 5.3.6. Looks like your PHP is to old. DOMDocument::saveXml() should work, too.